# Closing a JFrame Opened in Another JFrame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I am building an application which I need to open a JFrame in another JFrame while the first JFrame is disabled.

The problem is when I want to close the second JFrame I need to enable the first JFrame.

I have tried in several ways, but it is not working properly and I was not able to reach one goal in each of them. I need to reach both goals:

1. Disabling the first Frame when the second Frame is opened
2. Enabling it when the second Frame is closed.

Here is part of my code:

```
    private void jButton10ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    PaymentJFrame pjf = new PaymentJFrame();
    //setEnableValue(false);
    //enableFrame();
    this.setEnabled(false);
    pjf.setVisible(true);
    if (!pjf.isActive()){
        this.setEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

This code dose not enable the First Frame at all. 
I have tried to use it in another way by adding an `enable` when the second Frame is closed but it is not working:

```
    //Class in first Frame
    private void jButton10ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    PaymentJFrame pjf = new PaymentJFrame();
    //setEnableValue(false);
    //enableFrame();
    this.setEnabled(false);
    pjf.setVisible(true); 
} 
    //Class in second Frame 
    private void formWindowClosed(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    FinancialDocumentsJFrame.setEnableValue(true);
}
```

Dose any one know how can I reach these goals?

The first Frame is the main frame and the second frame is a class that I make the frame object from it in order to show and get more information from users.

I ma using netBeans IDE designer.

Comment: Why not use a modal [JDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html), instead of disabling/enabling `JFrame`

Comment: Sounds like something that [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) will be good for? Take a look at [How to use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)  (Bad!)  Either a dialog or a card layout as suggested in earlier comments would be better.

Comment: *"I'm using netBeans IDE designer."* My deepest condolences.  A tip:  Learn how to code Java GUIs and the designer will be a lot easier to make do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, a Swing application [should only have one JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice), other windows can be `JDialog` or somethign else. As for your question, use this code as an example. It uses a listener to detect the closing event of the second window. The following code should be in the (first) `JFrame` (it looks like you have a button there)

```
private void jButton10ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

JDialog paymentDialog = new JDialog();

MyFirstFrame.this.setEnabled(false);
paymentDialog.setVisible(true);

paymentDialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        MyFirstFrame.this.setEnabled(true);
    }
});
}
```

You can create your own dialog by extending `JDialog` as you did with the frames, and use the custom dialog in this code. Also instead of setting the `JFrame` enabled or disabled, you could consider using a [modal JDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html) that blocks actions to the JFrame while the dialog is active.

And further still, there is the `setAlwaysOnTop(boolean)` for Swing windows.

Answer (score 0):

use `this.dispose()`method `JFrame` has `dispose()` method for `JFrame` Close

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use jDialog as it was recommended by many people on the net.

I used a jDialog and copied all the objects I had used in the second jFrame.

It worked the way I wanted it to do.

My only problem is that why java hasn't prepared a different way to answer this need.

I'm using an action listener in the first jFrame to open the second Frame which I have used jDialog for it.

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    ActivityJDialog ajdf = new ActivityJDialog(this,true);
    ajdf.setVisible(true);
}
```

And I have copied everything I wanted to have into this jDialog.

```
public class ActivityJDialog extends java.awt.Dialog {

//Document Attributes 
int documentStatus = -1;
int documentType = -1;

/**
 * Creates new form AcrivityJDialog
 * @param parent
 * @param modal
 */
public ActivityJDialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();
    /*if(false) // Full screen mode
    {
        // Disables decorations for this frame.
        //this.setUndecorated(true);
        // Puts the frame to full screen.
        this.setExtendedState(this.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    }
    else // Window mode
    {*/
        // Size of the frame.
        this.setSize(1000, 700);
        // Puts frame to center of the screen.
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        // So that frame cannot be resizable by the user.
        this.setResizable(false);
    //}
}
```

Thank you all for helping.